# Filtering objects returned by the relation (set.all) in Django

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-models

I am trying to solve the filtering of objects returned by `set.all`. I would like to display objects that are strictly assigned to the currently logged in user.

Below is a pseudo-code that illustrates the situation.

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    pass
    
class Comment(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(... related_name='example')
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
```

In the generic detail "tag" view

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['author_objects'] = Comment.objects.filter(creator=self.request.user)
    return context
```

In a detail tag template, I am using `set.all` to return the callback objects. However, these are all assigned objects, and I would like to filter them.

```
{% for comment in tags.comment_set.all %}
     <a href="{% url 'comment-detail' comment.id %}">{{ comment.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried many solutions to display user-created comments (even with 'author objects', nested loops) but I get all assigned objects or nothing. I suspect that the context is not working, but it was about visualizing the situation in the best possible way.

Comment: So you only want the `comment_set` to contain `Comment`s with `self.request.user` as `creator`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `QuerySet` with a [**`Prefetch(…)`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to retrieve a filtered set of comments.

You do this by overriding the [**`get_queryset(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) with:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class MyView(SomeView):
    model = Tags
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'comment_set',
                queryset=Comment.objects.filter(creator=self.request.user)
            )
        )
```

There is no need to alter the `get_context_data`. By specifying the `Prefetch` object, `comment_set` will only contain comments with `self.request.user` as `creator`.

Comment: I am grateful for your help, all the best. https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem